# Div does not center in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an extremely simple issue. I have nested divs. where I am trying to center a div(.gridcontainer) in div(.main). If you run the below snippet, you can see that the div does center full in the main div. It leaves the spaces uneven on the either side horizontally and vertically.

I have tried a lot of fixes and even tried dynamically centering them on load through JS. But, somehow it does not achieve the results.

I just want it to be the exact size of the parent but have little spaces left on each sides evenly.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tops {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.70);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top_menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.welcome {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.welcome_message {
    font-family: 'Palanquin Dark', sans-serif;
    font-size: calc(2.5vw + 3vh);
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
}

.app_name {
    font-size: calc(1.5vw + 2vh);;
}

.gradientText {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFA07A, #8B0000);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.downloadButton{
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left:50%;
    background-color: white;
    width: 225px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-width: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}

.downloadButton:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: translate(-50%, -75%) scale(1.1);
}


.downloadText {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}


.iphone {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.iXFrame {
    position: absolute;
    height: 700px;
    width: 350px;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 75px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 50vh;

}

.gridcont{
    position : absolute;
    /*height: auto;*/
    width: auto;
    /*min-height: 95vh;*/
    min-width: 95vw;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hover.css/2.3.1/css/hover-min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Montserrat|Palanquin+Dark|Paytone+One|Rubik|Rubik+Mono+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <section class="mains ui">
        <div
            class="tops"></div>
            <!--.top_menu-->
            <div class="ui grid marg-reset">
                <div class="doubling two column row">
                    <div class="ui column welcome">
                        <h1 class="welcome_message"><span class="app_name">Example</span><br>we will<br>rock <br>you<br><span class="gradientText">Text</span></h1>
                        <a class="downloadButton" type="button" href="/app">
                            <div class="downloadText">Download Spotmi</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="ui grid gridcont">
                    <div class="doubling two column row">
                        <div class="ui column show_text">
                            <h1 class="emotion_message">Hello world</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui column emotion_show"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

This also poses an issue in the responsive nature of the site. Below are two screenshots. one of a HiDPI Laptop screen and other is a iphone X simulator. This even poses an issue there.

**iPhoneX size screen**. 
[image: iPhoneX size screen]

**Laptop Screen**. 
[image: Laptop Screen]

How exactly can I solve this?

Comment: Other than the `body` has a default margin, which `body {
 margin: 0;
}` will fix, your posted sample work, and if the margin adjustment won't be enough you have to post a sample that doesn't.

Comment: @dun32 I am using sematic UI. Is that similar of flexbox offers better performance?

Comment: @LGSon That's the reason I asked about the difference of flexbpx and sematicUI. I have updated my code though with complete html. This shows the issue now. And I alreasy had `margin` and `padding` set to 0.

Comment: @AakashDave No, you applied margin wrong, you should the `body` type, not `.body` class. I edited your code and it works just fine.

Comment: @LGSon oops! Missed the closure there. Well, it's weird it's running here. I have the same exact snippet in my project and it produces errors are show in the screenshot

Comment: @AakashDave Use the browsers dev.tools and you most like will see what goes on. And it wasn't only the closure you missed, you had a dot in front of the body, which will make it look for a class, not element type

Comment: @LGSon Trust me I have been on that for so long. I dont know what I am missing. Let me double check again and get back

Comment: @AakashDave If you don't find it, you'll have to strip down the code, little by little, so it is small enough to post here but still reproduce the issue.

Comment: @LGSon that's ok, I think it's always better to use native tools than libraries. But this is opinion based and off topic, sorry for that

Comment: @dun32 It is great to suggest another tech., though make sure the one being used doesn't already have it built-in, or else unaware users might ad it on top and get unpredictable render issues. I mean, most users picked a framework for a reason to begin with.

Comment: @LGSon ok, I understand, thanks :-)

Comment: @LGSon I tried checking the issue in the browser. On Safari as well as Firefox, it shows me the error as above. But on pasting the whole project in the snippet box here, everything works fine. What do you think can be the issue. And what tools do you suggest I should use for the debugging now?

Comment: @LGSon It's just hard for me to demonstrate the issue if this aberrations occur. Hence I am I asking.

Comment: Then paste me a link here, to your site where it has the issue, and I'll have a look later today, when I'm back by the PC.

Comment: @LGSon Hey, I really appreciate you helping me out on this. I am attaching the website here https://www.dropbox.com/s/aofa1vmzpv7vlkd/Website.zip?dl=0

Comment: First of, in general, when you use `100vw` on a parent, its scrollbar is not taken into account when the child is trying to center, hence the right hand side will look smaller, but if you measure the left/right distance to the browsers edge's you'll see it will be in the center.

Comment: Second, and in your case, the `<div class="ui grid">` has negative margins (-1rem) on all side and will also affect the `main` to be wider. The quick fix is to remove/reset those left/right margin to 0, and then also change the `min-width: 100vw` in your `.main` to `min-width: 100%`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185657/discussion-between-aakash-dave-and-lgson).

Comment: This is why I like bootstrap as disgruntled as they are about some things, if you have an outer div displaying flex with the d-flex class you can have the inner div with flex-fill w-100 h-100 and then for good measure justify-contents-center align-items-center classes on the outer div... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the giving the internal div that you want to center CSS properties:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

this usually solves my balancing issues xD

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy, but I already tried this. This issue has been solved. You can check the comments for the answer. i will post the answer shortly